# Deleting an item from table view using instrument automation ui testing

Tags: ios, testing, tableview

I am trying to delete the item from list in Recipes app using instrumental automation UI testing.i recorded the deletion for one item and i changed the same with other name but its not working please help me out.

Here is my code

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[" "].switches()["Delete MAggi "].setValue(<value>);

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()[" "].buttons()["Confirm Deletion for MAggi "].tap();

target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, assuming that you have a cell in the table view with a recipe called "MAggi", the following should work:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();

target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["MAggi"].switches()["Delete MAggi"].tap();

target.frontMostApp().mainWindow().tableViews()["Empty list"].cells()["MAggi"].buttons()["Delete"].tap();

target.frontMostApp().navigationBar().leftButton().tap();
```

Instead of trying to `setValue`, it seemed clearer to me to `tap()` the "Delete MAggi" button. Also, you need to make sure that you specify the correct table name in the square brackets after `.tableViews()`